# How to get the most frequent value in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table with column 'Price' and would need to get the most frequent value. What would be the eeasiest way?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be something like

```
SELECT price
  FROM (SELECT price, rank() over (order by cnt desc) rnk
          FROM (SELECT price, count(*) cnt
                  FROM your_table
                 GROUP BY price))
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

If there are two (or more) prices that occur equally as often, both will be returned by this query.  If you want to guarantee a single row, you'll need to tell us how you want to handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

My algorithm is as follows:

1. Step one: make distinct selection as a collection;
2. Step two: foreach item in distinct collection count the items found in the original collection as diffcollection;
3. Step three: select max from diffcollection.

Comment: This can be done with a single SQL statement...

Comment: But, does the algorithm differ?

Comment: No, but it's less efficient.